# Big gaps in android's HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an HorizontalScrollView and a Linear layout

```
   <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filesScrollerLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Programmaticaly I'm trying to add views in the linearLayout with the following way:

```
     LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.filesScrollerLayout);

     ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
     ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(this);
     ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(this);
     imageView1.setImageDrawable(Drawables);
     imageView2.setImageDrawable(Drawables);
     imageView3.setImageDrawable(Drawables);
```

The problem is that in the horizontalscroll view there are big gaps between the images. I just want the images to be next to each other. How can I succeed that?

Comment: Try to make horizotalScrollview width wrap_content

Comment: @Mehul Ranpara I've tried but it didn't work

Comment: The images are probably being scaled to a size smaller than the image view. So the image view's are next to each other but it appears like they aren't since their contents are smaller. Change your scaleType on the images to somethings like fit_start and see if that helps it

Comment: have you tried adding other views instead? E.g. simple View objects with specified width and height and a background color? That way you could see if it's a layout problem or if it has to do with image scaling as @dymmeh supposes.

Answer (score 5):

If the contents are ImageViews, set this:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

set the margins and padding to `"0dp"`

as here

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/filesScrollerLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using ImageView generated at runtime, use umagView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. You must scale down your images to make it work.

Use this :

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
profileImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 120, 120, false));