# android - spacing of items added to linear layout changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am adding pictures to a linearlayout programmatically.  This linearlayout is surrounded by a horizontalscrollview and part of a item layout for a listview.  When I have the pictures inline with the other view items, they are spaced next to eachother correctly:
[image]

However if I move the horizontalscrollview/linearlayout under the other view items, I get some weird spacing that android seems to do automatically:
[image]

So far I have tried relativelayouts, embedded linearlayouts, changing padding, changing margins, changing the width property of the linearlayout between match_parent, fill_parent, and wrap_content, but nothing changes this spacing.  It is always the same.

Here is the relevant code:

```
LinearLayout tmpLL = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llUpgrades);

        //remove previous list contents first
        tmpLL.removeAllViews();

        for(int i = 0; i<= tmpUpgradeList.size()-1; i++){

            ImageView tmpIB = new ImageView(getContext());
            Upgrade tmpUpgrade = tmpUpgradeList.get(i);
            Upgrade.setUpgradePic(tmpIB, tmpUpgrade, tmpUpgrade.Title()==null);
            tmpIB.setTag(position + ":" + i);
            tmpIB.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
            tmpIB.setMaxWidth(50);

            tmpLL.addView(tmpIB);

            tmpIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                      String[] split = ((String) v.getTag()).split(":");
                     runUpgradePopup(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
                }
            });

            tmpIB.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                     String[] split = ((String) v.getTag()).split(":");
                     clearUpgrade(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
                     return true;
                }
            });

        }
```

Layout of the one causing the error.  The other layout puts the cards next to each other correctly but all I have different is that it is a linear layout and removed the relevant relative placement calls:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnFRemoveShip"
            android:text="Remove"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFRowShipIcon"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnFRemoveShip"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvFRowShipTitle"
            android:text="error"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivFRowShipIcon"/>



        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnFRemoveShip">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/llUpgrades">
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try wrap_content for the scroll and linear layout.

Comment: nerp, tried scroll/wrap, linear/fill and scroll/wrap, linear/wrap but exact same results

Answer (score 0):

Took a couple days of rewording the question but finally found the answer.
Had to add this line before adding the image to the layout.

```
tmpIB.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Thread is here: [found answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029975/big-gaps-in-androids-horizontalscrollview)